# Disable $schema JSON autocompletion with Monaco

Tags: json, monaco-editor

I'm using the Monaco editor to build a JSON editing UI.

It seems if you use any Monaco setup for JSON (e.g. their home page demo, if you set it to JSON: https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor) then autocompletion (ctrl-space) always shows a `$schema` option.

I'm sure this is useful if you're intending to use JSON schemas, but I'm not. I want to implement my own autocompletion, so I don't want to disable it entirely, but I want to remove `$schema` from the options.

Adding a completionProvider seems to only add *additional* completions, not remove existing ones.

Is there any way to control this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

In your `package.json`, you should depend on `monaco-editor-core` instead of `monaco-editor`. This way you won't get any of the JSON language editing capabilities. I think you'd have to define the syntax highlighting yourself though...

Comment: Ah, interesting. I do want some of the other languages too though, so that won't work... Is there an easy way I could define a new language, like `schemaless-json`, which has everything from JSON, but no `$schema` option?

Comment: Sounds like you'd have to do a custom build yourself. Monaco's JSON support comes from the [monaco-json repository](https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-json/). Perhaps you can do some digging there to see if you can find anything useful.